# Create Taxonomy sub-term using CSOM and javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, taxonomy, term-store, client-object-model

in sharepoint managed metadata I found very little documentation on managing terms using javascript CSOM. I could create a taxonomy term directly under the term set but I want to create a term under another term as a child like in term store window.

```
 function execOperation(){
    //Current Context
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    //Current Taxonomy Session
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
    //Term Stores
    var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
    //Term Store under which to create the term.
    var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_Dmxzz8tIBzk8wNVKQpJ+xA==");
    //Term Set under which to create the term.
    var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("b49f64b3-4722-4336-9a5c-56c326b344d4");
    //Name of the term, LCID and a new GUID for the term.
    var newTerm = termSet.createTerm("India", 1033, "b49f64b3-4722-4336-9a5c-56c326b344a9");
    //newTerm.set_isAvailableForTagging(true);
    context.load(newTerm);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    alert("Term Created: " + newTerm.get_name());
     },function(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to add term under a any parent term, you should be needing two things:

- The Term store ID and relevant Term set
- The Parent Term ID (to which the new child term will be added)

The update code will be following:

```
     function execOperation()
     {
        //Current Context
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        //Current Taxonomy Session
        var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);

        //Term Stores
        var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();

        //Term Store under which to create the term.
        var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_Dmxzz8tIBzk8wNVKQpJ+xA==");

        //Term Set under which to create the term.
        var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("b49f64b3-4722-4336-9a5c-56c326b344d4");


        //get the parent term ID, say it's "cf46hujkl-3344-4336-9a5c-56c326b344d4"
        var parentTerm = termSet.getTerm("cf46hujkl-3344-4336-9a5c-56c326b344d4");

        //create new child term under the parent term
        var newTerm = parentTerm.createTerm("SharePoint Rocks", 1033, newGuid.toString());

        context.load(newTerm);
        context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        alert("Term Created: " + newTerm.get_name());
         },function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
        });}
```